# Does the variation of $I$ yield Bach tensor？

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, tensor-calculus, curvature, variational-calculus

For $$I_1=\int \sqrt{-g}C_{abcd}C^{abcd}d^4x,$$ where $C_{abcd}$ is the Weyl tensor. If we neglect the Gauss-Bonnet term this can be reduced to $$I_2=2\int \sqrt{-g}(R^{ab}R_{ab}-\frac {1}{3} R^2)d^4x.$$ My question is, does the variation of $I_1$ yield the Bach tensor or the variation of $I_2$ give the Bach tensor? I've heard that the Gauss-Bonnet term is crucial to produce the Bach tensor, is that true?

Answer (score 1):

I am too low reptutation to make what should be a comment, but these two actions of yours should yield the same set of field equations up to a boundary term (Gibbons–Hawking–York term) precisely because of Gauss-Bonnet.

Therefore, in 4 dimensions, they both give the Bach tensor provided that you do not care about topological terms.